# Dialog boxes only work when tablet is tipped! DDouble letterss?

Tags: keyboard, 3.1-honeycomb, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

One of my Samsung Galaxy Tabs v10.1 will not accept certain dialog input unless the tablet is some other direction than right-side up (left portrait, right portrait or upside down all work fine). For example hold the power button to turn it off, it asks "are you sure you want to shutdown?" It ignores all touches including "Ok" or "Cancel".

Also when you use the keyboard it often inserts two letters on one key push.

Thinking that this HAS to be a software issue I rooted and installed clockwork Mod ROM manager and restored an image from another working tablet. No change. This is the weirdest issue to date with my tablet adventures. Any idea what is going on?

UPDATE: Samsung repair said the screen was bad. They didn't elaborate but at least I have a working tablet now!

Comment: That sounds like a screen problem, and gravity is affecting whether or not a connection is being properly made.  I would guess a loose ribbon cable or something like that.

Comment: no because the tablet works fine other than the two issues i mentioned above and you can lay it flat on a table and depending on the image orientation it will either work (upside down image) or won't work (right side up image) with the tablet in the same position

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  That's really weird!

Comment: further testing reveals the double letter issue only happens when tablet is right side up as well.

Comment: @Michael: Since the solution was a Samsung repair, please leave that as an answer and "accept" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung replaced the screen (it was under warranty)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a full wipe, maybe it's a glitch. Otherwise it sounds like a hardware problem. By the way, I have understood that it's a bad idea to use a Nandroid backup from another device since some device-specific information could be moved as well.

Comment: I had already done a wipe...nothing seemed to change it so I sent it back to Samsung. Also, I've had no issues restoring from other identical devices. If some device specific data is moved I haven't encountered any issues as of yet.

Comment: At least older Samsung phones had a /efs partition which contains the IMEI and MAC addressses for WiFi/BT. This is not supposed to be copied, messes up networks if two devices with the same details are active. Don't know if this is present on tab10, haven't rooted mine.